# how to use jquery masonry with embed-able tweets (iframes)

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, twitter, masonry

I am trying to use Masonry with multiple embed-able tweets. But i am running into the issue of the elements overlapping each other.

One method i tried was using the imagesLoaded plugin as per the reference guide, but that didnt work as i dont think the iframe of each tweet hasnt fully loaded i think.

i have tried to call masonry only when the page has loaded but i still have the issue of the tweets overlapping.

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {

    var $container = $('#panel');
    $container.masonry({
      columnWidth: 300,
      itemSelector: '.elem'
    });
});
```

I dont know what to do, is there a way i can some how figure out the height of an embedable tweet before i send it to the client so i can set it as inline style of the iframe. here is the JSON data returned from the twitter API.

```
=============statuses/oembed============

    { cache_age: '3153600000',
      url: 'https://twitter.com/Cristiano/statuses/477052670197653504',
      height: null,
      provider_url: 'https://twitter.com',
      provider_name: 'Twitter',
      author_name: 'Cristiano Ronaldo',
      version: '1.0',
      author_url: 'https://twitter.com/Cristiano',
      type: 'rich',
      html: '<blockquote class="twitter-tweet"><p>Insane first half against the aliens! <a href="https://twitter.com/FALCAO">@Falcao</a>, we&#39;ll show them how we play football! <a href="https://twitter.com/search?q=%23GALAXY11&amp;src=hash">#GALAXY11</a> <a href="http://t.co/z0FzRHz6gG">http://t.co/z0FzRHz6gG</a> <a href="http://t.co/pGJ4F1AcO0">pic.twitter.com/pGJ4F1AcO0</a></p>&mdash; Cristiano Ronaldo (@Cristiano) <a href="https://twitter.com/Cristiano/statuses/477052670197653504">June 12, 2014</a></blockquote>\n<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>',
      width: 550 }
```

Server side i am using node.js with express

Comment: Why are you using `iframe` when you have a json with the html? Just create new `div` for each json entry and append `"html"` contents to it.

Comment: this is what i am doing , the javascript within the html element pulls in an iframe

Comment: i need a method to figure out the height of all the iframes before i call masonry

Answer (score 7):

```
window.twttr = function (d, s, id) {
    var t, js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return; js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    return window.twttr || (t = { _e: [], ready: function (f) { t._e.push(f) } });
}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');

twttr.ready(function (twttr) {
    twttr.events.bind('loaded', function (event) {
        //DO A MASONRY RELAYOUT HERE
        msnry.layout();
    });
});
```

This worked well for me so far.

Comment: Could you outline what this code does? Where does it come from? Any documentation on it?

Comment: first part is the twitter library, second part is about attaching an event (our masonry relayout) to the 'loaded' event of the widgets.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a jquery each over your '.elem' elements after your iframes have loaded, find the iframe inside, get the height, and set the .elem height to the iframe height, and then run masonry.

```
$('.elem').each(function(elem,index){
    var height = $(elem).find('iframe').height();
    $(elem).height(height);
});
//masonry reload here
```

EDIT:

Depending on how you're loading your iframes, if you're using jquery ajax, you could easily add to your complete, success, or `.done()` callbacks.

Comment: How do I check when each frame has loaded?? Or when the last I frame has loaded

Comment: Edited answer to answer your question

Comment: I noticed that the code block could use a closing ); - it is too small of an edit for me to make.